# React redux map reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have looked everywhere but nothing is working. I am trying to increment/decrement position based on which one they select on screen.

I am using useSelector to try and get a slice of the code.

```
const leagueSettings = useSelector((state) => state.drafts.rosterSettings);
```

But I cannot get the mapping to work. The state never updates. I can see that I am sending in an updated count for the position and the correct position.

My action.js

```
    export const ADD_ROSTER_SPOT = "ADD_ROSTER_SPOT";
export const REMOVE_ROSTER_SPOT = "REMOVE_ROSTER_SPOT";

export const addRosterSpot = (position, count) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_ROSTER_SPOT,
    position: position,
    amount: count
  };
};

export const removeRosterSpot = (position, count) => {
  return {
    type: REMOVE_ROSTER_SPOT,
    position: position,
    amount: count
  };
};
```

my reducer.js

```
 import { ADD_ROSTER_SPOT, REMOVE_ROSTER_SPOT } from "../actions/draft";

let initialState = {
  leagueSettings: [], // list of league settings,
  rosterSettings: [
    { Position: "QB", amount: 1 },
    { Position: "WR", amount: 1 },
    { Position: "RB", amount: 1 },
    { Position: "TE", amount: 1 },
  ],
  drafted: [], // list of players drafted by others
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ROSTER_SPOT:
        return state.rosterSettings.map(pos => {
            if (pos.Position === action.position) {
            return {...pos, amount: pos.amount + 1}
            }
            console.log(state)
            return pos;
        });
    case REMOVE_ROSTER_SPOT:
      return state.rosterSettings.map((pos) => {
        if (pos.Position === action.position) {
          return { ...pos, amount: pos.amount - 1 };
        }
        return pos;
      });
    default: return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the code inside the reducer because it is not updating the state correctly

try using this in the "ADD_ROSTER_SPOT" case in reducer

```html
let filteredState = state.rosterSettings.filter((eachPos) => {
 if (eachPos.Position === action.Position) {
    eachPos.amount = eachPos.amount + 1;
    return eachPos;
  }
  return eachPos;
});
let newState = Object.assign({}, state, { rosterSettings: filteredState });
return({ ...newState });
```

Comment: I see this change the array correctly. But I must be doing something wrong with useSelector afterwards cause it does not update the state.

Comment: check the name you gave for the reducer in the root reducer. It must me same as the name you gave in the useSelector.

Comment: I figured it out. The above code got me on the right path but i needed to return the state as this 

return {
              ...state,
              newState
          }

Answer (score 0):

Please check where the drafts reducer is defined, and what is your code in rootReducer?